# filter a List according to multiple contains

Tags: list, scala, collections, filter, scala-collections

I want to filter a `List`, and I only want to keep a string if the string contains `.jpg`,`.jpeg` or `.png`:

```
scala>  var list = List[String]("a1.png","a2.amr","a3.png","a4.jpg","a5.jpeg","a6.mp4","a7.amr","a9.mov","a10.wmv")
list: List[String] = List(a1.png, a2.amr, a3.png, a4.jpg, a5.jpeg, a6.mp4, a7.amr, a9.mov, a10.wmv)
```

I am not finding that `.contains` will help me!

Required output:

```
List("a1.png","a3.png","a4.jpg","a5.jpeg")
```

Comment: Based on your need, it seems that you need to include the String that **ends with** (rather than contains) these extensions. Example: ```jpg.txt```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `filter` method.

```
list.filter( name => name.contains(pattern1) || name.contains(pattern2) )
```

If you have undefined amount of extentions:

```
val extensions = List("jpg", "png")
list.filter( p => extensions.exists(e => p.matches(s".*\\.$e$$")))
```

Answer (score 4):

To select anything that contains one of an arbitrary number of extensions:

`list.filter(p => extensions.exists(e => p.contains(e)))`

Which is what @SergeyLagutin said above, but I thought I'd point out it doesn't need `matches`.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use `filter()` with an appropriate function performing your selection/predicate?

e.g.

```
list.filter(x => x.endsWith(".jpg") || x.endsWith(".jpeg")
```

etc.