# Scala : adding to Scala List

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am trying to append to a List[String] based on a condition But List shows empty

Here is the Simple code :

```
object Mytester{

  def main(args : Array[String]): Unit = {
    val columnNames = List("t01354", "t03345", "t11858", "t1801566", "t180387685", "t015434")
    //println(columnNames)

    val prim = List[String]()

    for(i <- columnNames) {
      if(i.startsWith("t01"))
        println("Printing i : " + i)
        i :: prim :: Nil
    }

    println(prim)
  }
}
```

**Output :**

```
Printing i : t01354
Printing i : t015434
List()

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 3):

This line, `i :: prim :: Nil`, creates a new `List[]` but that new `List` is not saved (i.e. assigned to a variable) so it is thrown away. `prim` is never changed, and it can't be because it is a `val`.

If you want a new `List` of only those elements that meet a certain condition then filter the list.

```
val prim: List[String] = columnNames.filter(_.startsWith("t01"))
// prim: List[String] = List(t01354, t015434)
```

Comment: Actually `i :: prim :: Nil` creates `List[Any]`.

Answer (score 1):

**1) why can't I add to List?**

`List` is immutable, you have to mutable List (called `ListBuffer`)

definition

```
scala> val list = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String]()
list: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer()
```

add elements

```
scala> list+="prayagupd"
res3: list.type = ListBuffer(prayagupd)

scala> list+="urayagppd"
res4: list.type = ListBuffer(prayagupd, urayagppd)
```

print list

```
scala> list
res5: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer(prayagupd, urayagppd)
```

**2. Filtering a list in scala?**

Also, in your case the best approach to solve the problem would be to use `List#filter`, no need to use for loop.

```
scala> val columnNames = List("t01354", "t03345", "t11858", "t1801566", "t180387685", "t015434")
columnNames: List[String] = List(t01354, t03345, t11858, t1801566, t180387685, t015434)

scala> val columnsStartingWithT01 = columnNames.filter(_.startsWith("t01"))
columnsStartingWithT01: List[String] = List(t01354, t015434)
```

**Related resources**

[Add element to a list In Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19610571/432903)

[filter a List according to multiple contains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26842860/432903)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what jwvh explained.
Note that in Scala you'd usually do what you want as

```
val prim = columnNames.filter(_.startsWith("t01"))
```