# Scala-String filter operation from a new learner

Tags: string, scala, filter, substring, rdd

There are some Strings like:

```
"A,C,D"   "A,C"   "A,B"   "B,C"   "D,F"   "G,D,H"
```

If I want to filter those Strings by the key: A,C. That means, if the String contains A or C, I will take it. For example, through this rule, I will get:

```
"A,C,D"   "A,C"   "A,B"   "B,C"
```

How should I code this function?

Comment: What do you have so far? Put your samples in a list, and search for a function in List, which looks promising. Write a function which can solve solve your problem for a single case. Combine the function with the list function.

Comment: `.filter(_.matches(".*(A|C).*"))`

Answer (score 0):

You should try this for yourself as this is a good learning exercise for beginners in Scala like you mentioned!

So here is an idea on how you could do it! There are a million other ways, but this is just for you to get started!

```
scala> val l = List("A,C,D",   "A,C",   "A,B",   "B,C",   "D,F",   "G,D,H")
l: List[String] = List(A,C,D, A,C, A,B, B,C, D,F, G,D,H)

scala> l.filter(elem => elem.contains("A") || elem.contains("C"))
res1: List[String] = List(A,C,D, A,C, A,B, B,C)

scala>
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming your input is string as below,

```
scala> val input = """"A,C,D"   "A,C"   "A,B"   "B,C"   "D,F"   "G,D,H""""
input: String = "A,C,D"   "A,C"   "A,B"   "B,C"   "D,F"   "G,D,H"
```

you can split by `"` and then filter out empty strings. Then filter those which contains `A` | `C`

```
scala> input.split("\"").map(_.trim).filter(_.nonEmpty).filter(e => e.contains("A") || e.contains("C"))
res1: Array[String] = Array(A,C,D, A,C, A,B, B,C)
```

Or you can also apply regex pattern something like `.*A.*|.*C.*`,

```
scala> input.split("\"").filter(_.nonEmpty).filter(_.matches(".*(A|C).*"))
res2: Array[String] = Array(A,C,D, A,C, A,B, B,C)
```

**Also see:**

[filter a List according to multiple contains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26842860/432903)

Answer (score 0):

```
val samples = List ("A,C,D", "A,C", "A,B", "B,C", "D,F", "G,D,H")
samples.filter (s => s.contains ('A') || s.contains ('C')) 
> List(A,C,D, A,C, A,B, B,C)
```

Note how you raised the important keywords *contains* and *filter* (though you will not always that lucky).